# Best practices for passing tokens via messaging system (proxy)

Tags: oauth, token, publish-subscribe, identityserver3, openid-connect

We recently started using IdentityServer3. There is a requirement to have the call go via a messaging system (proxy) because of network limitations, which is responsible for routing to the RS.
OAuth asks for TLS or an end to end trusted channel.
Now the message brokers are part of a trusted network, but is it a good idea to have the bearer tokens be in clear text at any point midway? Is this something we should be concerned about or trust the messaging system? Or any other recommended approach?

Thanks!